# MATLAB: uiopen AND get the name of that file?

Tags: matlab

I have a GUI that has pushbuttons. You push the button, it allows you to choose a file to open then loads that file into the workspace using uiopen('load'). This part works fine:

Then I would like it to return the name of the file it just opened, so that I can use it for telling the next part of the program which data to look at, and to get the name of the opened file to display in an edit box in the GUI itself. First issue more vital than second. Any help would be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the function 'uigetfile' is usually used for openning standard dialog box for retrieving files, and the format is like:

```
filename = uigetfile

or

[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile(FilterSpec)
```

This function, displays a modal dialogbox that lists files in the current folder and enables you to selector enter the name of a file. If the file name is valid and the fileexists, uigetfile returns the file name as astring when you click Open. Otherwise uigetfile displaysan appropriate error message, after which control returns to the dialogbox. You can then enter another file name or click Cancel.If you click Cancel or close thedialog window, uigetfile returns 0.

one example could be:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.m','Select the MATLAB code file');
```

Also, you can use 'uigetdir' for doing the same for directories.

In addition, you can check this link: [for matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uigetfile` to get the name of the file and open it using `load(filename)`.